Azure Openai Whipser REST endpoints
I wanted to use Whisper deployed through Azure OpenAI but I am having trouble finding the right resources for it.
I am trying to integrate a translator using Whisper in a flutter app that will take multilingual input and give out the output in english.
Right now the transcription is working using this endpoint:
https://<dep>.openai.azure.com/openai/deployments/<name>/audio/transcriptions?api-version=2024-02-01 
and structuring the request like:
var uri = Uri.parse(whisperEndpoint);
          var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri)
            ..headers['api-key'] = whisperApiKey
            ..files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('file', filePath));

What is the endpoint for translation, tts and other services?
I have tried sending the text transcribed by whisper back to be translated but I'd prefer direct translation by whisper

You can use below endpoint for trnaslation.
https://reproaistudio.openai.azure.com/openai/deployments/<deplymentname>/audio/translations?api-version=2024-06-01

And it will convert it into English text.
Here, is the sample output with Bengali as the input file language.

If you want to convert this text to speech then use  tts-1 or tts-1-hd models in azure openai.
Make sure you have your open ai resource in supported region of above models

Can you provide the headers and body for this endpoint and also
do you know the endpoints for the tts api and their headers and body.
Thanks

Check this for whisper https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/whisper-quickstart?tabs=command-line%2Cpython-new&pivots=rest-api#rest-api  it is all same only endpoint is different

And for tts https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/text-to-speech-quickstart?tabs=command-line#rest-api  here you need to give text and voice required. In the same page at the starting mentioned available voices

thanks for your help, i have not tested it yet but i'll close the thread :)
